# Accessing Elasticsearch 5.0.0 from remote host

Tags: java

I set network.host to 0.0.0.0 for accessing it from outside.When I started elasticsearch using bin/elasticsearch it throws following error.

```
[2017-01-03T12:13:11,154][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [xhyfAMj] publish_address {10.71.71.188:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2017-01-03T12:13:11,166][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [xhyfAMj] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2017-01-03T12:13:11,236][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xhyfAMj] stopping ...
[2017-01-03T12:13:11,358][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xhyfAMj] stopped
[2017-01-03T12:13:11,359][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xhyfAMj] closing ...
[2017-01-03T12:13:11,384][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xhyfAMj] closed
```